# Is there a difference between increasing a TCP socket timeout vs manually retrying the socket connection?

Tags: sockets, tcp

I inherited code that attempts to establish a TCP socket to diagnose a device's connectivity with certain urls. In some cases, the TCP socket will timeout after the timeout threshold we set. My question is if there's a difference between manually retrying the socket connection vs just increasing the timeout threshold?

Bear in mind that this is a diagnostic tool being used on devices that are being installed and configured, so their network configuration might change in the middle of a socket connection. Would a TCP socket account for network changes (like gateway, DNS or local IP) and establish a connection before it times out (assuming the network changes are finalized before the socket would normally timeout) or is it necessary to establish a new socket connection? Or is there no real difference between increasing the timeout vs manually retrying the socket connection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

timeout can occur because of multiple reasons, but imagine next situation:

1. packet is sent
2. some strange failure happen between your host and device and packet is completely lost (dropped)
3. you get timeout

now, you've increased timeout - this will not change the situation

if you have retries - **new** packet will be sent in case of timeout and if failure is transient, then you will eventually establish connection

conclusion - timeout should be set to some reasonable, but quite small value, and you should have multiple retries, again some reasonable number.

Comment: That's such an obvious answer, I don't know why I didn't think about that. Thanks for clarifying!